# Combine_first and null values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

df1:

```
     0    1
0   nan 3.00
1 -4.00  nan
2   nan 7.00
```

df2:

```
      0   1    2
1 -42.00 nan 8.00
2  -5.00 nan 4.00
```

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

df3:

```
      0    1    2
0   nan 3.00  nan
1 -4.00  nan 8.00
2 -5.00 7.00 4.00
```

This is what I'd like df3 to be:

```
      0    1    2
0   nan 3.00  nan
1 -4.00  nan 8.00
2   nan 7.00 4.00
```

(The difference is in `df3.ix[2:2,0:0]`)

That is, if the column and index are the same for any cell in both df1 and df2, I'd like df1's value to prevail, even if that value is `nan`. `combine_first` does that, except when the value in df1 is `nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky way to do it.  First, align `df2` with `df1`, which creates a frame indexed with the union of `df1`/`df2`, filled with df2's values.  Then assign back df1's values.

```
In [325]: df3, _ = df2.align(df1)

In [327]: df3.loc[df1.index, df1.columns] = df1

In [328]: df3
Out[328]: 
    0   1   2
0 NaN   3 NaN
1  -4 NaN   8
2 NaN   7   4
```